# NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined when I try to use a parser

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a problem with my code when I want to use BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time

for i in range(len(link_website)):
    page = requests.get(link_website[i])
    parser = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
    shoes_name[i] = (parser.find(class_="title")).h1.text
```

Here’s what I get as error :

```
parser = BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
NameError: name 'BeautifulSoup' is not defined
```

How do I solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you import `BeautifulSoup`?

Comment: Yes I import with pip

Comment: no, `pip` is used to install. To import a package, you have to use the keyword `import`. Write `import BeautifulSoup` at the top of your script

Comment: Yes I  import this at the top of my script :

Comment: `import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import webbrowser
import datetime
import time`

Comment: Can you edit your question with the imports? Also if you've imported it as `bs` so replace `BeautifulSoup` with `bs`.

Comment: If you're writing `import BeautifulSoup as bs` then you're gonna have to use `parser = bs(page.content,'html.parser')` instead

Comment: I just changed with bs it work ! Thanks you verry much !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to import package

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
shoes_name={}
for i in range(len(link_website)):
    page = requests.get(link_website[i])
    parser = soup(page.content,'html.parser')
    shoes_name[i] = (parser.find(class_="title")).h1.text
```